# Representing minimum, maximum, mean and current value graphically in html

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have been trying to represent data graphically using d3 bullet charts but it was not appropriate. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961
Are there any other alternatives to represent data graphically; i.e a maximum, minimum, mean and current value?

Answer (score 0):

I used this

- [androidplot](http://androidplot.com/)

but on google:

- [chartdroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)
- [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)
- [charts4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)

Choose what fit your needs. (I really don't understand what you mean with "a maximum, minimum, mean and current value" but it's not important, read docs and example and see which gives to you what you want.)

There are much others.